# Downloading a filestream in an MVC 4 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to MVC and I am trying to create a download page for a website but have run into a problem. The page has a number of files available that you can download when you click on a button associated with it.

When a request to download is received the file is retrieved from a remote server through a socket in blocks and written to the response stream. This all works fine when there is just one request but gets all tangled up if there is a double click or another user makes a request at the same time.

The question is how can I queue the requests so that one request to download is complete before the second and subsequent requests are actioned.

Any ideas or help is appreciated.

here is the Download Action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Download(string itemID)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DOWNLOAD REQUEST");

        var downloadReq = new DownloadInfo() { ID = Convert.ToInt64(itemID), CurrentBlockNum = -1 };
        var username = User.Identity.Name;
        var request = new IDeskPacket(PacketType.Download, username, downloadReq);

        //get the first block of data
        var ideskResponse = (IDeskPacket)await RequestChannel.Instance.SendAync(request);
        if (ValidResponse(ideskResponse))
        {
            //initialise data
            var downloadInfo = (DownloadInfo)ideskResponse.Data;
            bool flush = false;

            //build the response stream
            Response.Clear();
            if (!Response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DOWNLOAD REQUEST FINISHED - DISCONNECTED");
                Response.End();
                return View("Error");
            }
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + GetshortFilename(downloadInfo.Filename));
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", downloadInfo.FileSize.ToString());

            try
            {
                //loop until the end of the data or an invalid response
                do
                {
                    //write the received data to the response stream
                    Response.BinaryWrite(downloadInfo.DataBlock);

                    //null the data block out so it doesn't get sent back to the server later
                    downloadInfo.DataBlock = null;

                    //so we don't cache to much flush after every "other" data request
                    if (flush) Response.Flush();
                    flush = !flush;

                    //send request for next block of data
                    ideskResponse = (IDeskPacket)await RequestChannel.Instance.SendAync(ideskResponse);

                    //check the response and cache the data if valid
                    if (ValidResponse(ideskResponse)) downloadInfo = (DownloadInfo)ideskResponse.Data;

                } while (downloadInfo.CurrentBlockNum > 0);

            }
            catch (HttpException httpEx)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(httpEx.Message);
                //Response.Clear();
            }
            //signal the end of the response stream
            Response.End();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DOWNLOAD REQUEST FINISHED - FILE DOWNLOAD FINISHED");

            return View("Index", "UserDownload");
        }
        else
        {
            //redirect to error
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DOWNLOAD REQUEST FINISHED - INVALID SERVER RESPONSE");
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: to download the contents of a remote web page you can use [WebClient.DownloadStringAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync.aspx) method. You call this method which will register an IOCP within the operating system and return immediately. During the processing of the entire request, no threads are consumed on your server. Everything happens on the remote server.

Comment: This could take lots of time but you don't care as you are not jeopardizing your worker threads. Once a response is received the IOCP is signaled, a thread is drawn from the thread pool and the callback is executed on this thread. But as you can see, during the entire process, we have not monopolized any threads.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Its not a remote webpage i am downloading they are zip files that reside on the other side of the socket connection that i can only get through the socket. The asp app requests a block of data and then when it receives a response it writes it to the response stream then gets the next block. It doesn't block the UI or anything and works fine when just one request is happening. All i want to do really is queue the download actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Delegates for building a queue and user BeginInvoke so it can process your request asynchronusly, for an example I have built a delegate for mail sending :

```
delegate bool MailSender(string to, string cc, string subject, string message);
public static void SendMailAsync(string to, string cc, string subject, string message)
    {
        MailSender sender = new MailSender(SendMail);
        AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(DisposeMail);
        sender.BeginInvoke(to, cc, subject, message, callback, "");
    }

private static void DisposeMail(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        AsyncResult delegateResult = (AsyncResult)result;
        MailSender delegateInstance = (MailSender)delegateResult.AsyncDelegate;
        delegateInstance.EndInvoke(result);
    }
```

Where "SendMail" ius a function responsible for required processing in your case remote downloading but this will be called async by delegate. Hope this helps